# How to access csv files from sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, csv

I have a CSV file called: "products.csv".
This file contains products and the first line contains the columns names.

My question is how to create a view in sqlite that access to this file and use it as a normal view such as:

```
SELECT ID, NAME FROM PRODUCTS
```

I'm looking for a solution without importing data to a table.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible. Why don't you want to import the data?

Answer (score 1):

While the better/more efficient approach would be to import the CSV file into a real table (Which is easy to do with sqlite), the [CSV extension module](https://www.sqlite.org/csv.html) does pretty much exactly what you want.